# to reduce time complexity of my python programe

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to find all subsequences of length 3 within a list. My program's complexity is too high, so I want to reduce my program's time complexity. My code is here.

```
def generate(lst):
    end = len(lst)
    for i in range(0, end - 2):
        for j in range(i + 1, end - 1):
            for k in range(j + 1, end):
                yield lst[i], lst[j], lst[k]

for a, b, c in generate([6, 3, 88, 4]):
    print(a, b, c)
```

Comment: Although this question might technically be on-topic here, I think that you may find https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ to be more suited to your needs.

Comment: Are `subsequence_triplets` and `generate` the same function? Also are you happy with a standard library based solution i.e. itertool.combinations or did you want to implement the algorithm?

Comment: yup, those are the same. sorry for the silly mistake. Actually, I want to implement the algorithm.

Comment: What are you actually trying to return? The question says subsequences, but your code produces combinations that aren't subsequences. There are only two subsequences in that list: `[6, 3, 88]` and `[3, 88, 4]`.

Comment: If you're really trying to return all combinations, you can't reduce the time complexity. The number of combinations is O(n^3), and you can't produce them in less time. You can use `itertools.combinations()`, but it will have the same time complexity.

Comment: ok. I got it. @Barmar

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to how [`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) is implemented:

```
from itertools import combinations
print(list(combinations([6, 3, 88, 4], 3)))
```